# Working with Visio Javascript API and WOPI Host

Tags: visio, ms-wopi, javascript-api-for-office

We have developed a WOPI Host that serves Word and Visio files to the Wopi Client (Which is Office for the web).  We have been trying hard to see if we can get "shape info" of the shapes in the visio files that are loaded by the wopi client.  We referred to the Microsoft documentation on using the Visio Javascript API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/visio-javascript-reference-overview#visio-javascript-api-reference , however, we cannot get it to work.  We see in the sample code that that the embed url for the visio file from the SharePoint is being used.  However, when we try the same, we get an error as below:

(Please click on the below link to see the image... apparently I don't have enough credits to post images :-( )
[Error with Visio file from SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWzgs.png)

On the other hand, when we use the url from WOPI host, the file loads in the iFrame, however, we can't get any information of the shape that is selected and we get an error which is not of type OfficeExtension.Error and the error is shown as empty as seen below:

(Please click on the below link to see the image... apparently I don't have enough credits to post images :-( )

[Loading Visio from WOPI Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbD9n.png)

Now the question that we have are as follows:

1. Does Visio Javascript API work the same way irrespective of the way the visio files are loaded?  (i.e., with Visio from Sharepoint and Visio from WOPI host)?
2. If the answer to question 1 is yes, what could be the reason the sample code doesn't work. Any specific areas that we can look in to?
3. If the answer to question 1 is NO, then is there a way to get shape info of the shapes in visio files that are served by the WOPI host?

Comment: It is amazing you got it to work in principle. But I believe you must be the first guy on this planet who tried this setup  I believe microsoft support (from a office core dev team) may be your only option to get it working. You can try cloud partner storage program.

Comment: Regarding shape info, you can get it directly from Visio file, in case new (vsdx) format is used. It's just open xml, there are examples how to get shape info from it. Mean is your wopi host serves files it has full access to the file contents right.

Comment: Ah wait a sec. Just checked the screenshot. It is trying to render using Microsoft's online viewer, not your custom wopi server. This is allowed only to the members of cloud storage program, as far as I remember (there is "white list" by microsoft). I.e. this viewer check the source of the request against a fixed list.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, sorry that am responding to this conversation pretty late.  However, regarding the above comment, WOPI does serve the files indeed and has access to the file contents, however, we are trying to see if we can get basic info of the shapes from the Office for the web iFrame that is loaded using the WOPI client.  Another thing that isn't that clear to me is, the sample code provided in the visio javascript api only talks about developing inside a webpart (sharepoint) and does not mention anything about using this api in a normal web application. Any idea?

Comment: The script file needs to be on a SharePoint site, because for Visio API you are using, that site should be explicitly whitelisted (otherwise it will block access and say "something went wrong" which actually means failed CORS call). This is done basically to make sure the customers pays for Visio license I suppose. I am not sure if you can overcome that with custom WOPI. Means, Visio javascript code and your page run on different domains. creating web parts as such is not required, it's just a common way to host script on sharepoint site.